# how to block twitter accounts on behalf of others with tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, bots, tweepy

I have an idea to make a twitter bot that block annoying accounts:

my question is can I block accounts on behalf of other user?

I am using  tweepy

I already have tokens for my account

Comment: no, that would make no sense from a security standpoint to allow a third party to access internals of an account, they would have to use their own API key and tokens, unless the docs say that that is possible which I would highly doubt

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you have access tokens for the other user. You can get these by using the sign-in with Twitter API, and have the other user go through that process to authorize your app.

Comment: No that is not the case.  couple of years age I saw some services can tweet in users accounts. I want to do same thing but instead of that I would like to block accounts (ads bots ) for the users so these annoying tweets be hidden.

Comment: I obviously misunderstand your question. You can get Auth tokens for users if they login via your app. You can use those tokens to block accounts on behalf of those users. This applies now and it also applied a couple of years ago. Please provide the code that is not working for you.